# Capturing incoming UDP packet fails

Tags: networking, macos, tcpdump

My Environment:

```
Mac OS X 10.8.5 (IP: 192.168.10.5)
CentOS 6.5 (IP: 192.168.10.8)
```

I'm trying to capture UDP incoming packet on OS X.

I tried on the Terminal of OS X

```
# tcpdump -In udp portrange 6000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Then, on CentOS 6.5

```
$ echo "test" | nc -w 1 -u 192.168.10.5 6000
nc: Write error: Connection refused
```

The connection was refused.

However, when I run a program (UDP echo server) made by Unity (5.1.3f) to receive UDP packet on OS X, the connection was not refused.

```
$ echo "test" | nc -w 1 -u 192.168.10.5 6000
test
```

Which part of the configuration of OS X should I check?

Comment: Here is just a suggestion if you are wanting to capture packets. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a great tool for such a task. I understand that you may be limited to a terminal and it doesn't answer this question (Hence why this is not a answer, but a comment). I just wanted to make you and others aware of this great tool for packet analysis.

Comment: Have you checked the Firewall on the Mac system? A lot of systems like to filter UDP packets due to the "point and fire" denial-of-service capabilities.

Comment: @Gamerb I have checked Firewall on Mac. The firewall is not turned on. And thank you about the Wiershark.

Comment: @sevenOfNine What is the problem here? Packet sniffers like tcpdump and Wireshark don't create UDP listener sockets. So the IP stack will send back an ICMP "destination unreachable: port unreachable" message if it receives a UDP datagram for a port with no open listener socket. So far you've described expected behavior, so I'm not sure what problem you're seeing that you'd like solved.

Comment: @Spiff Wireshark does capture UDP packets.  And the problem being his Mac will not accept UDP packets, but his CentOS does.

Comment: @gamerb, I didn't say it wouldn't capture them, I said it wouldn't open a listener socket (it wouldn't keep the sender process from seeing "connection refused"). Second, his CentOS box is always the sender, not the receiver.

Comment: Thank you for you, all. My problem is on MacOSX (receiver): 1) Unity app can receive UDP packet. 2) Termnal (tcpdump command) cannot receive UDP packet. Other than tcpdump on Terminal, should I run some other program?

Comment: Does your wireless network use encryption (WEP, WPA, WPA2)?

Comment: @Spiff Yes. But, now I do not remember which one I use.

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless driver may not be decrypting packets while in 802.11 Monitor Mode, so tcpdump may not be able to tell that they're UDP packets.

Redo your test without passing `-I` to `tcpdump`. That will allow tcpdump to view the interface as an Ethernet instead of putting it in 802.11 Monitor Mode.

Note that even though tcpdump will capture the packets, it won't prevent the IP stack from sending back an ICMP "destination unreachable: port unreachable" message if it receives a UDP datagram for a port with no open listener socket. So `nc` on the sending machine will still say "connection refused" if you're not running something like Unity to receive those packets.

Comment: I tried to test without `-I`. However, I still have the same problem of "Connection refused".

Comment: @sevenOfNine That's what I said you'd see. Did tcpdump show the incoming UDP data gram on port 6000?

Comment: No. tcpdump did not show the incoming UDP data gram on port 6000. By the way, I did not write part of my Environment, which may be causing this problem. I will write the information.

Answer (score 0):

I did not write part of My Environment, which may be important for this problem.

I am using VMware.

My Environment:

```
Mac OS X 10.8.5
CentOS 6.5 on VMWare Fusion 6.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

No firewall setting on MacOS X 10.8.5

Mac OS X(Host OS) network
- en0 : 192.168.10.4
- vmnet1 : 172.16.99.1
- vmnet8 : 172.16.173.1

CentOS(Guest OS) network (connected with "Bridge" setting)
- eth0 : 192.168.10.8
- lo : 127.0.0.1
```

1) From CentOS to Mac OS X through en0 on Mac OS X.

- tcpdump on Mac OS X does not show incoming UDP packet ("connection refused" is shown on CentOS 6.5)
- Unity app (UDP receiver) shows incoming UDP packet (no error message on CentOS 6.5)

On CentOS

```
# echo "test" | nc -w 1 -u 192.168.10.4 6000
nc: Write error: Connection refused
```

On Mac OS X

```
# tcpdump -n udp portrange 6000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

2) From CentOS to Mac OS X through  vmnet8 on Mac OS X.

- tcpdump on Mac OS X shows incoming UDP packet as show below.

On CentOS

```
$ echo "test" | nc -w 1 -u 172.16.173.1 6000
```

On Mac OS X

```
# tcpdump -n udp portrange 6000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
07:28:39.958576 IP 192.168.10.8.59866 > 172.16.173.1.6000: UDP, length 5
```

---

So, at least if I use vmnet8, I can send UDP packet from CentOS to Mac OS X.
I have no problem using vmnet1, also.